# Post form data to Server(Android)

Tags: java, android

I need to submit my registration form details to server api. I have tried one method by calling a function on button click.But nothing is geting posted in the server. **I need to post data as Content-type:Form-Data, because server doesn't respond on anything else. Help me please, thanks!!**

```
 public class Login extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        String userName;
        String password;

        public Login(String user, String pass) {
           userName = user;
            password = pass;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }



        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                        
                        .addEncoded("user",userName)
                        .addEncoded("pass",password)
                        .build();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://www.autotrack.rs/android_juzna_backa/login.php")
                    .post(formBody)
                    .build();

            try {
                Call call = client.newCall(request);
                Response response = call.execute();
                System.out.println(response.body().string());

            }catch (Exception m)
            {
                m.printStackTrace();
            }
            Response response = null;
            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                System.out.println(response.body().string());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(!response.isSuccessful())
            {
                try {
                    throw new IOException("Unexpected: "+response);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Comment: @Zoe Thank you! I didn't know.

Comment: @Zoe thank you for cleaning up android studio tags recently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the **setType** method and use the **addFormDataPart**.

```
RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
        .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
        .addFormDataPart("somParam", "someValue")
        .build()

Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://www.autotrack.rs/android_juzna_backa/login.php")
                    .post(formBody)
                    .build();
```